# How to add vertex in between vertices in a loop

Tags: vertices

I have a model that resembles a circle. I added loop cuts. I need to add vertices in between vertices that came with those loop cuts. The screenshot below describes my issue more clearly.

[image]

Comment: If you can temporarily fill these loops (a few ways to do it), then it seems CTRL+R would work, then deleting temporary faces and edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could duplicate the loop ( <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>D</kbd> )and fill it with Bridge Edge Loops, select edge ring and scale edges to 0 with individual origins then merge by distance( <kbd>M</kbd>  ->  <kbd>B</kbd> ) and delete only edges and faces( <kbd>X</kbd>  ->  <kbd>O</kbd> ). You could hide unselected and then unhide everything while working to make it easier to see and select right geometry( <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>H</kbd>  and  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>H</kbd> ) Those will be floating vertices not connected to anything.
[image]